# I cannot use string And CString class in MFC

Tags: string, mfc, c-strings

I wanted to use `CString` class in MFC

but I couldn't

I don't know why `CString` is undefined

I'm using visual studio 2015

please help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgi1D.png

here is my code

Comment: I wrote a wrong code but CString was also same

Comment: Are you using MSVC Express Edition? If yes, it does not include MFC framework. You should use Professional Edition of Visual Studio to in order to use MFC.

Comment: Please don't include pictures of your source code but include your sourc code.

Comment: You have a typo: You should use CString not Cstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo: You should use `CString` not `Cstring`